# How to add WHERE condition for last 12 months in DAX query

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
EVALUATE
FILTER
(
SUMMARIZE (
'Product_Category',
'Product_Category'[id],
'Product_Category'[Sale-Date],
'Product_Category'[Store],
'Product_Category'[Description]
),
'Product_Category'[Acronym] = "Test Product"
)
ORDER BY 'Product_Category'[Sale-Date]
```

I have the above sample DAX expression to get product sales data. I want to add some sort of a WHERE clause such that only records where the "[Sale-Date]" is in the last 12 months are returned.

I cant seem to figure out how to add that condition, any one please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL `WHERE` is `FILTER` in Dax. You already are using one filter criteria:

```
'Product_Category'[Acronym] = "Test Product"
```

To expand what you have:

```
EVALUATE
FILTER
(
SUMMARIZE (
'Product_Category',
'Product_Category'[id],
'Product_Category'[Sale-Date],
'Product_Category'[Store],
'Product_Category'[Description]
),

  'Product_Category'[Acronym] = "Test Product" &&
  'Product_Category'[Sale-Date] >= DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1, MONTH(NOW()), DAY(NOW()))

)
ORDER BY 'Product_Category'[Sale-Date]
```

Comment: Would have posted as a comment if it allowed formatting

Comment: Am new to DAX and am not understanding the " %reference date minus one year%" part. Do you know of some sample code for this?

Comment: It depends on how you define current (selected?) date

Comment: For example, using current date `DATE(YEAR(NOW()-1),MONTH(NOW()), DAY(NOW())`

Comment: I want to use this as the source query when getting data into my .pbix file. So every time i refresh the data, it should only get data for the past 12 months from the date of the refresh.

Comment: The expression DATE(YEAR(NOW()-1),MONTH(NOW()), DAY(NOW()) seems to be missing a second closing ) right?

Comment: When i add that second ), i get an error that "Too many arguments were passed to the FILTER function. The maximum argument count for the function is 2"

Comment: When i use exactly the expression you provided with out a second closing ), i get an error that "The syntax for 'ORDER' is incorrect"

Comment: Don't have access to PowerBI so made a mistake. Edited the answer - does this work for you?

Comment: Looks like we are getting there, this executes with out error in management studio but doesn't return any rows and i have records for 2019. My date values are in format:   4/22/2019 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Corrected another mistake - could you give it another go?